# Hello World does not show up at all. I tried to refresh the layout, but nothing changed

Tags: android, android-studio

When I start the program, I can't see the *helloworld* and I looked at your answers about the issue, but it does not work at all.

Here's what it appears:

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Update the question with your dependencies in `build.gradule`

Answer (score 0):

do u have something like this

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

in your builde.gradle?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are connected to a good network

Check this checkbox

> Goto >file -> other settings -> Under build, execution, and deployment
>   -> you will see Gradle. uncheck the checkbox offline work.

Click apply.

and rebuild your project.